# Discord.py - Streaming Youtube Live into Voice

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, youtube, discord.py

I'm back on the stacks, was banned from asking questions because they were terrible apparently, but I need help on something I've done a lot of research on but cannot find my answer;

I need to be able to stream a youtube live stream's audio into a VC for radio music using discord.py Rewrite. I've been looking at Youtube_DL- and/or FFMpeg-related internet posts and all were either outdated (discord.py==0.16.x) or involved downloading youtube videos (can't do that with ongoing streams).

And I've also tried to look through the discord.py v0.16.12 [voice_client.py `create_ytdl_player`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/44a4a473ab00c1c1fb26cdf42a4a7b58285d8994/discord/voice_client.py#L440). But to no avail, I could not find any solutions.

This is my current situation in my code. It is a background task in one of my cogs.

```py
    @loop(seconds=5)
    async def check_voice(self):
        try:
            channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(819346920082112532)
        except NotFound:
            print("[IR] `Infinite Lofi` voice channel not found. Stopping check_voice loop.")
            self.check_voice.cancel()
            return

        try:
            infinite_lofi = await channel.connect(timeout=2, reconnect=True)
        except ClientException:
            return
        else:
            print("[IR] Connected to voice channel.  Loading from config livestream URL...")
            channel = await self.bot.fetch_channel(780849795572826213)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(780859270010503188)
            ctx = await self.bot.get_context(message)

            # infinite_lofi.play()  <<< Looking to play a youtube live stream audio.
```

According to the discord.py docs, I need an AudioSource to pass into [`VoiceClient.play()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=voiceclient#discord.VoiceClient.play). 
**My goal is to play LIVE audio, not download. In other words, stream.** 
If you need an example, I am looking to stream from [this lofi radio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A).

## Update

I've looked at a comment by Łukasz Kwieciński to check an [example on the official Discord.py Repository](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py). I only needed the "from_url" function under the class YTDLSource. However, my problem now is that it will play from a stream but will stop playing after 2-4 seconds of streaming, and then about 1-2 minutes later I get a statement in stdin saying "skipping 20 segments ahead, expired from playlists" in yellow and it plays, then stops again.

```py
player = await YTDLSource.from_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A", loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
infinite_lofi.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f"Player error: {e}")) 
# ^^^ plays for a few seconds and stops, repeats every 1-2 minutes.
```

Comment: Why have you looked at some old branch? Take a look at the [new example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py) there's an  example of streaming music from youtube.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Ah, of all places I've looked, this must be the only place I haven't looked. Thanks for this tip.

Comment: I added an update to my post about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have code for my music bot that streams any youtube video, whether it's a live stream or a regular video, without downloading it. This code also doesn't stop the music after 2-4 seconds of streaming, which is the problem you're having. Another plus is that it has complete queue functionality, which is similar to that of bots like Groovy and Rythm. Along with that, it has other commands such as `remove` and `clear` that will either remove a specified song in the queue or will clear the entire queue. Other commands include `np`, which will show the current video playing; `queue`, which will print out the entire music queue; `vol`, which will show the current volume of the voice client; `vol <integer between 1 and 100>`, which will change the volume percentage based on the inputted number, and the regular `join` and `leave` commands that are used to make the bot join a voice channel. Try copy-pasting this code into your cog, and it should work for you without any issues.

````py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import asyncio
import itertools
import sys
import traceback
from async_timeout import timeout
from functools import partial
import youtube_dl
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

# Suppress noise about console usage from errors
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdlopts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': 'downloads/%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0'  # ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpegopts = {
    'before_options': '-nostdin',
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = YoutubeDL(ytdlopts)


class VoiceConnectionError(commands.CommandError):
    """Custom Exception class for connection errors."""


class InvalidVoiceChannel(VoiceConnectionError):
    """Exception for cases of invalid Voice Channels."""


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):

    def __init__(self, source, *, data, requester):
        super().__init__(source)
        self.requester = requester

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.web_url = data.get('webpage_url')
        self.duration = data.get('duration')

        # YTDL info dicts (data) have other useful information you might want
        # https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md

    def __getitem__(self, item: str):
        """Allows us to access attributes similar to a dict.
        This is only useful when you are NOT downloading.
        """
        return self.__getattribute__(item)

    @classmethod
    async def create_source(cls, ctx, search: str, *, loop, download=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

        to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=search, download=download)
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f"Queued [{data['title']}]({data['webpage_url']}) [{ctx.author.mention}]", color=discord.Color.green())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        if download:
            source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        else:
            return {'webpage_url': data['webpage_url'], 'requester': ctx.author, 'title': data['title']}

        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source), data=data, requester=ctx.author)

    @classmethod
    async def regather_stream(cls, data, *, loop):
        """Used for preparing a stream, instead of downloading.
        Since Youtube Streaming links expire."""
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        requester = data['requester']

        to_run = partial(ytdl.extract_info, url=data['webpage_url'], download=False)
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, to_run)

        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(data['url']), data=data, requester=requester)


class MusicPlayer:
    """A class which is assigned to each guild using the bot for Music.
    This class implements a queue and loop, which allows for different guilds to listen to different playlists
    simultaneously.
    When the bot disconnects from the Voice it's instance will be destroyed.
    """

    __slots__ = ('bot', '_guild', '_channel', '_cog', 'queue', 'next', 'current', 'np', 'volume')

    def __init__(self, ctx):
        self.bot = ctx.bot
        self._guild = ctx.guild
        self._channel = ctx.channel
        self._cog = ctx.cog

        self.queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.next = asyncio.Event()

        self.np = None  # Now playing message
        self.volume = .5
        self.current = None

        ctx.bot.loop.create_task(self.player_loop())

    async def player_loop(self):
        """Our main player loop."""
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()

        while not self.bot.is_closed():
            self.next.clear()

            try:
                # Wait for the next song. If we timeout cancel the player and disconnect...
                async with timeout(300):  # 5 minutes...
                    source = await self.queue.get()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return self.destroy(self._guild)

            if not isinstance(source, YTDLSource):
                # Source was probably a stream (not downloaded)
                # So we should regather to prevent stream expiration
                try:
                    source = await YTDLSource.regather_stream(source, loop=self.bot.loop)
                except Exception as e:
                    await self._channel.send(f'There was an error processing your song.\n'
                                             f'```css\n[{e}]\n```')
                    continue

            source.volume = self.volume
            self.current = source

            self._guild.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda _: self.bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.next.set))
            embed = discord.Embed(title="Now playing", description=f"[{source.title}]({source.web_url}) [{source.requester.mention}]", color=discord.Color.green())
            self.np = await self._channel.send(embed=embed)
            await self.next.wait()

            # Make sure the FFmpeg process is cleaned up.
            source.cleanup()
            self.current = None

    def destroy(self, guild):
        """Disconnect and cleanup the player."""
        return self.bot.loop.create_task(self._cog.cleanup(guild))


class Music(commands.Cog):
    """Music related commands."""

    __slots__ = ('bot', 'players')

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.players = {}

    async def cleanup(self, guild):
        try:
            await guild.voice_client.disconnect()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            del self.players[guild.id]
        except KeyError:
            pass

    async def __local_check(self, ctx):
        """A local check which applies to all commands in this cog."""
        if not ctx.guild:
            raise commands.NoPrivateMessage
        return True

    async def __error(self, ctx, error):
        """A local error handler for all errors arising from commands in this cog."""
        if isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
            try:
                return await ctx.send('This command can not be used in Private Messages.')
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass
        elif isinstance(error, InvalidVoiceChannel):
            await ctx.send('Error connecting to Voice Channel. '
                           'Please make sure you are in a valid channel or provide me with one')

        print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
        traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)

    def get_player(self, ctx):
        """Retrieve the guild player, or generate one."""
        try:
            player = self.players[ctx.guild.id]
        except KeyError:
            player = MusicPlayer(ctx)
            self.players[ctx.guild.id] = player

        return player

    @commands.command(name='join', aliases=['connect', 'j'], description="connects to voice")
    async def connect_(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel=None):
        """Connect to voice.
        Parameters
        ------------
        channel: discord.VoiceChannel [Optional]
            The channel to connect to. If a channel is not specified, an attempt to join the voice channel you are in
            will be made.
        This command also handles moving the bot to different channels.
        """
        if not channel:
            try:
                channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
            except AttributeError:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="No channel to join. Please call `,join` from a voice channel.", color=discord.Color.green())
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                raise InvalidVoiceChannel('No channel to join. Please either specify a valid channel or join one.')

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if vc:
            if vc.channel.id == channel.id:
                return
            try:
                await vc.move_to(channel)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                raise VoiceConnectionError(f'Moving to channel: <{channel}> timed out.')
        else:
            try:
                await channel.connect()
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                raise VoiceConnectionError(f'Connecting to channel: <{channel}> timed out.')
        if (random.randint(0, 1) == 0):
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('')
        await ctx.send(f'**Joined `{channel}`**')

    @commands.command(name='play', aliases=['sing','p'], description="streams music")
    async def play_(self, ctx, *, search: str):
        """Request a song and add it to the queue.
        This command attempts to join a valid voice channel if the bot is not already in one.
        Uses YTDL to automatically search and retrieve a song.
        Parameters
        ------------
        search: str [Required]
            The song to search and retrieve using YTDL. This could be a simple search, an ID or URL.
        """
        await ctx.trigger_typing()

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc:
            await ctx.invoke(self.connect_)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)

        # If download is False, source will be a dict which will be used later to regather the stream.
        # If download is True, source will be a discord.FFmpegPCMAudio with a VolumeTransformer.
        source = await YTDLSource.create_source(ctx, search, loop=self.bot.loop, download=False)

        await player.queue.put(source)

    @commands.command(name='pause', description="pauses music")
    async def pause_(self, ctx):
        """Pause the currently playing song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_playing():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I am currently not playing anything", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        elif vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.pause()
        await ctx.send("Paused ⏸️")

    @commands.command(name='resume', description="resumes music")
    async def resume_(self, ctx):
        """Resume the currently paused song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        elif not vc.is_paused():
            return

        vc.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resuming ⏯️")

    @commands.command(name='skip', description="skips to next song in queue")
    async def skip_(self, ctx):
        """Skip the song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        if vc.is_paused():
            pass
        elif not vc.is_playing():
            return

        vc.stop()
    
    @commands.command(name='remove', aliases=['rm', 'rem'], description="removes specified song from queue")
    async def remove_(self, ctx, pos : int=None):
        """Removes specified song from queue"""

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        if pos == None:
            player.queue._queue.pop()
        else:
            try:
                s = player.queue._queue[pos-1]
                del player.queue._queue[pos-1]
                embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f"Removed [{s['title']}]({s['webpage_url']}) [{s['requester'].mention}]", color=discord.Color.green())
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
            except:
                embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f'Could not find a track for "{pos}"', color=discord.Color.green())
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    @commands.command(name='clear', aliases=['clr', 'cl', 'cr'], description="clears entire queue")
    async def clear_(self, ctx):
        """Deletes entire queue of upcoming songs."""

        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        player.queue._queue.clear()
        await ctx.send('**Cleared**')

    @commands.command(name='queue', aliases=['q', 'playlist', 'que'], description="shows the queue")
    async def queue_info(self, ctx):
        """Retrieve a basic queue of upcoming songs."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        if player.queue.empty():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="queue is empty", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        seconds = vc.source.duration % (24 * 3600) 
        hour = seconds // 3600
        seconds %= 3600
        minutes = seconds // 60
        seconds %= 60
        if hour > 0:
            duration = "%dh %02dm %02ds" % (hour, minutes, seconds)
        else:
            duration = "%02dm %02ds" % (minutes, seconds)

        # Grabs the songs in the queue...
        upcoming = list(itertools.islice(player.queue._queue, 0, int(len(player.queue._queue))))
        fmt = '\n'.join(f"`{(upcoming.index(_)) + 1}.` [{_['title']}]({_['webpage_url']}) | ` {duration} Requested by: {_['requester']}`\n" for _ in upcoming)
        fmt = f"\n__Now Playing__:\n[{vc.source.title}]({vc.source.web_url}) | ` {duration} Requested by: {vc.source.requester}`\n\n__Up Next:__\n" + fmt + f"\n**{len(upcoming)} songs in queue**"
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f'Queue for {ctx.guild.name}', description=fmt, color=discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.author.display_name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name='np', aliases=['song', 'current', 'currentsong', 'playing'], description="shows the current playing song")
    async def now_playing_(self, ctx):
        """Display information about the currently playing song."""
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        if not player.current:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I am currently not playing anything", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        
        seconds = vc.source.duration % (24 * 3600) 
        hour = seconds // 3600
        seconds %= 3600
        minutes = seconds // 60
        seconds %= 60
        if hour > 0:
            duration = "%dh %02dm %02ds" % (hour, minutes, seconds)
        else:
            duration = "%02dm %02ds" % (minutes, seconds)

        embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f"[{vc.source.title}]({vc.source.web_url}) [{vc.source.requester.mention}] | `{duration}`", color=discord.Color.green())
        embed.set_author(icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url, name=f"Now Playing ")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name='volume', aliases=['vol', 'v'], description="changes Kermit's volume")
    async def change_volume(self, ctx, *, vol: float=None):
        """Change the player volume.
        Parameters
        ------------
        volume: float or int [Required]
            The volume to set the player to in percentage. This must be between 1 and 100.
        """
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I am not currently connected to voice", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        
        if not vol:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f" **{(vc.source.volume)*100}%**", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        if not 0 < vol < 101:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="Please enter a value between 1 and 100", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        player = self.get_player(ctx)

        if vc.source:
            vc.source.volume = vol / 100

        player.volume = vol / 100
        embed = discord.Embed(title="", description=f'**`{ctx.author}`** set the volume to **{vol}%**', color=discord.Color.green())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.command(name='leave', aliases=["stop", "dc", "disconnect", "bye"], description="stops music and disconnects from voice")
    async def leave_(self, ctx):
        """Stop the currently playing song and destroy the player.
        !Warning!
            This will destroy the player assigned to your guild, also deleting any queued songs and settings.
        """
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        if not vc or not vc.is_connected():
            embed = discord.Embed(title="", description="I'm not connected to a voice channel", color=discord.Color.green())
            return await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        if (random.randint(0, 1) == 0):
            await ctx.message.add_reaction('')
        await ctx.send('**Successfully disconnected**')

        await self.cleanup(ctx.guild)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
````

Comment: Trying to play a song.. I'm not getting any music output. Can you provide an example of typing a command in discord?

Comment: @Chris For example, let's say your bot's command prefix is a comma. So, you could do `,play never gonna give you up` and it should play [Rick Astley's song](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ) from YouTube. Also, note that this is code for a cog, so placing this in your main code file will not work. You have to place it in a cog file.

Answer (score 1):

I have a better and simple work around this one

You can also test this , I got same quality as that of streaming with no issues.

```
FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'noplaylist':'True'}

voice = get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
    info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
    I_URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(I_URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
    voice.play(source)
    voice.is_playing()
```

Comment: Idk why but this isn't working either.. It's still stopping soon after starting it...

Comment: @SUPERMECHM500 Just copy the below code and if it still doesn't work, then let me know.
https://pastebin.com/r0QZfGDQ

Comment: @SUPERMECHM500
Type in discord in the channel with the bot **!play {yt-url}**

E.g. **!play** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCmp56tSSmA

Comment: @SUPERMECHM500 Are you using any vps or any containers ??

Use [Replit](https://replit.com/) for best performance and running bot for 24 x 7.

Replit is free and can be used for this purpose.

Comment: I am already using replit for all of my bots, the issue is playing live streams smoothly. Your code doesn't solve my issue. Unfortuantely, the answer I've accepted hardly works either, so I ask that you look at my [code](https://replit.com/@SUPERMECHM500/Kyaru#cogs/music.py) on replit. When you arrive, click "Code" at the top of the box, then open root/cogs/music.py. I had to change the format a little bit but it still fails to work for **livestreams**.

Comment: @SUPERMECHM500 I appreciate your effort. But can You please test this [code](https://pastebin.com/7xKmr4KW) in a separate repository with replacing **Token** with your bot token and then run the command.

Comment: Tell me if the **livestream** still fails to work or not.

Comment: This above **code** will help you to stream 96% smoothly. There might be hiccups and errors in the console (just ignore them).

Comment: It still does it, are you using a different audio engine or something?

Comment: @SUPERMECHM500 I think you must get a different bot token as this **code** works perfectly for me and there is no such kind **stream** failing issue

Comment: @SUPERMECHM500 Can you tell me what is the command that you are running ??

Comment: I am running `!p https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5qap5aO4i9A`. Please note that your code that you provided is also incomplete and would cause errors. `https://replit.com/@SUPERMECHM500/Testing-Console#main.py`

Comment: Hi, building a bot of my own and used this code. It worked amazingly. I had problems with other ways of doing it (long response/streaming wait times), but yours is instant. Although I cant figure out exactly how it works. Is there anyway you could explain your process in depth? Thanks!

Comment: @Phippre Thanks man, at least someone got my code working.
How my code works:
1. First it uses youtube-dl module to extract info of given youtube url. ( return a json list)
2. I use that json to locate url of mp3 of that youtube url.
3. I uses discord module to get input source for audio codec and bitrate information.
4. Then it is just playing code and nothing else (:

Comment: @Phippre If you want more instant than youtube-dl, then I will suggest you use pytube. I prefer pytube over youtube-dl. If you want pytube code, contact me on discord [NIP | device#1992]. I had some more codes to play a song by song search only.

Comment: @Pydeveloper Thanks! I appreciate the explanation. Ill be sure to hit you up on disc.

Answer (score 0):

I have a even more simple solution:
(it is coded not very well, i am an engineer...but it works ^^)

```
@client.command()
async def playlive(ctx,*,arg):
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'noplaylist':'True'}

    url1 = arg.split(" ")
    url2 = url1[0].replace("[","")
    url = url2.replace("]","")
    
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if voice and voice.is_connected():
        await voice.move_to(channel)
    else:
        voice = await channel.connect()
    ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS)
    with ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
        I_URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
        print(I_URL)
        source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(I_URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
        voice.play(source)
        voice.is_playing()
```